# Worker node in kops cluster goes to not ready state as load increases

Tags: kubernetes, kops

I deployed my frontend and backend application in my kops cluster on AWS ec2 with master size of t2 medium , when I increase the load on my applications, my both worker node goes to not ready state and the pods changes their state to pending state,
how can I resolve this issue my cluster is in production at moment.

Answer (score 0):

You should firstly run `kubectl get events -n default` to see why the nodes go into `NotReady`.

Usually your cluster is overloaded. Try using [cluster autoscaler](https://kops.sigs.k8s.io/addons/#cluster-autoscaler) to dynamically manage your cluster capacity. Also ensure you have proper resource requests on your Pods.